# How would I trim an image to fit an audio - Moviepy

Tags: python, moviepy

I am trying to show an image while audio is playing, and when the audio is done playing the image disappears.

This is as far as I got:

```py
image1 = mpy.ImageClip(image1_path).set_audio(mpy.AudioFileClip(audio1_path))
```

The problem with the above code is that the image will remain visible even after the audio is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.set_duration()`:

```
audio = mpy.AudioFileClip(audio1_path)
image1 = mpy.ImageClip(image1_path).set_audio(audio).set_duration(audio.duration)
```